# How to configure state in ionic blank app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I cretaed a new ionic blank app intuit there are two html pages: 1 index.html and a category.html. I configured the states and then added controller in app.js file but it is not working.

This is my state configurations:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('camera',{
            url:"/camera",
            cache: false,
            controller:"CameraCtrl",
            templateUrl:'index.html'
        })
        .state('category', {
            url: "/category",
            templateUrl: "category.html",
            controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
        })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/camera');

})
```

And this is my controller:

```
.controller('CameraCtrl',function($scope,$state){
  $scope.menu = function() {
    console.log('yesytest');
      $state.go('category');
      // window.location = "category.html";
  };

})
```

This is my app.js. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: There are a couple of things that can go wrong. Make sure you include all required AngularJS files, then make sure your app is properly initialized with ng-app or what ever tag is user to bootstrap the application now. Then make sure you've initialized the application in JS correctly, also make sure your controller present in the Html with ng-controller. These are some of the things that can go wrong

Comment: When you add a question like please include your HTML file, your JS files (don't include library files) and may be a tree hierarchy of your files ...

Comment: i am using only one js file i.e. app.js, and i added the controller in my html also.    How to initialise ng-app?

Comment: Thanks,it was my mistake i done some wrong things in index.html file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I only had 15 minutes to mock this together, Let me know if this works for you and if you need any further assistance drop me a response.

**Controller**

```
var example = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers',]);

example.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })                                   
  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
      }
    }
  })                                  
  .state('tab.camera', {
    url: '/camera',
    views: {
      'camera': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/camera.html'
      }
    }
  })                                    
  .state('tab.category', {
    url: '/category',
    views: {
      'category': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/category.html'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');
});
```

[>>> Working Example <<<](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7wFIP_wVh_yLUVhbTBQX3ZicEk/view?pli=1)

Comment: Thanks,it was my mistake i done some wrong things in index.html file

Comment: No problem Munavvar, If there is any other Ionic related quesitons I can help you with just hola. Good luck with your project.

Comment: i have another question. currently we are getting ios version as universal app. is there any solution to convert that universal app to iPhone only ?no need iPad

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this will work but you could try the following:

Navigate to project/platform/ios/ and open the xcode project. 
Deployment info > There you can switch it to either universal, iphone or ipad.

Let me know if you manage to get this working.

Comment: Yes, this is working form me, is there any other option in out cordova files?.or is this is a good practice?

Comment: Not 100% sure about the cordova files but the above should work without any problems

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.i have one more question shall i ask here?

Comment: Maybe ideal to post as a seperate question but fire away.